# Japanese flashcards

Tags: packages, document-classes, cjk, japanese, flashcards

I wanted to make some flashcards for learning japanese. I've found the `flashcard` class and some japanese output package (`ucs`, `CJK`). But they don't seem to work together. I've coded the following as an example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{a4paper}{geometry}
\documentclass[avery5371,frame]{flashcards}

\usepackage[encapsulated]{CJK}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,german,brazilian]{babel}
\newcommand{\cjktext}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{cyberbit}#1\end{CJK}}


%\cardbackstyle[\small\selectlanguage{english}]{empty}
%\cardfrontstyle[\selectlanguage{german}\Large]{headings}
\cardfrontfoot{\cjktext{日本語}}

\begin{document}


\begin{flashcard}{\cjktext{がくせい}}
1) student
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

The *.pdf file was build without any errors by pdflatex, but the *.pdf itself doesn't contain any of the japanese character.

Does anyone know how I could fix this, or does perhaps anyone know packages or classes which are more adequate here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using XeLaTeX, you should be using the `xeCJK` package instead of `CJK`. The code is then much simpler:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{a4paper}{geometry}
\documentclass[avery5371,frame]{flashcards}

\usepackage[english,german,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro}
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}      % set your favorite Latin-based font here

\cardbackstyle[\small\selectlanguage{english}]{empty}
\cardfrontstyle[\selectlanguage{german}\Large]{headings}
\cardfrontfoot{日本語}

\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}{がくせい}
1) student
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've chanded `\setmainfont` to `\setromanfont`, now it workes to my full satisfaction!

Answer (score 2):

Your example works for me, so I suspect the issue is with the `cyberbit` font rather than `ucs` or `CJK`. Have you set up the `cyberbit` font for use with LaTeX? Instructions for doing so can be found [here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/cs/cjk.html#examples).

Alternatively, get the [`wadalab` fonts](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=wadalab), and use `maru`, `min` or `goth` instead of `cyberbit`.

Comment: my LaTeX editor TeXnicCenter cannot show chinese character, what should I do? I am using Miktex 2.9 distro.

Comment: @xport, have you installed support for Eastern languages from the Windows setup CDs? Also, TeXnicCenter didn't have good support for UTF-8, I'm not sure if that's still the case with the latest versions. You might want to try TeXworks instead (also included with MikTeX).

Comment: It hasn't worked for a long time (every new idea was followed by more complications) but now I finally figured it out. I required `fontspec,xunicode.xltxtra` then I used `\newfontsface\kanji{Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro}` (I'm using a mac), and every font is embedded in `\kanji{ ... }`. I know it's not the nicest solution but at least it finally works.

Comment: @beyeran, are you using XeLaTeX instead of LaTeX? If so, using xeCJK rather than CJK is the best solution. It calls fontspec and xunicode, plus after selecting a font for use with CJK, you won't need to explicitly mark CJK text in your document. I've added an answer using xeCJK.